# What is the replacement for setDrawCubic() which is deprecated for MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

Answer: 
If you are using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and still using `setDrawCubic()` method which is deprecated, the solution is to use :

```
public enum Mode {
    LINEAR,
    STEPPED,
    CUBIC_BEZIER,
    HORIZONTAL_BEZIER
 }
```

Which is defined in the *LineDataSet.java* class in the library.

```
mySet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
```

So next time dont use `mySet.setDrawCubic(true);` just use the above and the desired `enum` value.

Comment: * The previous was for kotlin, Updated code above! :)

Answer (score 5):

Now you have to use:

```
dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
```